# Solution for handling multiple Twitter accounts?

Tags: twitter

I have 3 Twitter accounts.

What's the best solution for handling multiple Twitter accounts?

I've been using [splitweet](http://en.splitweet.com) for some time, but it's buggy, and its support for retweets is limited.

Any good solution for multiple account tweeting?

Comment: Question and responses should be specific to WEB-based clients, otherwise this question should be asked on http://superuser.com instead...

Answer (score 6):

Most modern clients should support multiple accounts. I can recommend [Tweetdeck](http://www.tweetdeck.com/) It supports multiple accounts.

Comment: i love tweet deck :D

Answer (score 2):

There are evidently a lot of solutions, so I'll just add [Brizzly](http://brizzly.com) to the mix here, which I have been quite fond of.

Comment: +1 for Brizzly - it is (slowly) getting better as well.

Answer (score 1):

I manage four accounts through [Tweetie](http://www.atebits.com/tweetie-mac/) without any issues, though pretty much any client will be able to do this for you.

Comment: Just for info of anyone reading this, Tweetie is a a desktop client for Mac that is either for-pay or ad-supported.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, I have been using [HootSuite](http://hootsuite.com/) for a long time. It's a webapp so I have it everywhere. I use it to manage my Twitter and Facebook accounts. Some other social networks are also supported. I have never been disappointed.

Answer (score 1):

[Cotweet](http://cotweet.com) is designed to handle multiple accounts, and is a very slick web-app to boot.  One of the best (designed) I've ever used.

Comment: Just for info of anyone reading this, Cotweet is a for-pay,  enterprise-oriented desktop client.

Comment: @Daphna - 100% incorrect.  Cotweet Standard is FREE and completely web-based, as is their paid Enterprise product.  It is NOT a 'desktop client' : http://cotweet.com/products/product-comparison/

Answer (score 0):

Researching this today I also came across Multwiple which I have not tried, but this blog post is a more recent (Feb 2011) endorsement than the others mentioned here. I have not yet tried it as I'm not sure which one to choose yet and don't want to waste too much time trying them all. http://www.calvinshub.com/2011/02/managing-multiple-twitter-accounts-with-multwiple